# Nevopy for games with two or more players

Tags: python, machine-learning, evolutionary-algorithm

I have tried nevopy to make a good KI for Connect Four. In fitness_fuction, I wanted to let a model play against a randomly chosen opponents of the population, but I wasn't able to use the population variable although it was global. Is there a way to use the population the fitness function whenever the fitness of one model is dependent on others? How else should nevopy be used for games with multiple players?

I would like to use nevopy because it is easy and not so difficult to understand like neat-python.

I expected that I could use the population variable in the fitness function baut that didn't work.